# Device is unable to write ANR trace into trace.txt

Tags: android, android-anr-dialog

LG G2(Android version: 4.4.2) device unable to write ANR trace into trace.txt. Is it issue with the device or firmware?

Following is the error given in adb logs.

05-20 10:05:32.015   964  1003 E ActivityManager: ANR in com.verizon.pushtotalkplus (com.verizon.pushtotalkplus/.PocMainActivity)
05-20 10:05:32.015   964  1003 E ActivityManager: PID: 8309
05-20 10:05:32.015   964  1003 E ActivityManager: Reason: Input dispatching timed out (Waiting because the touched window has not finished processing the input events that were previously delivered to it.)

05-20 10:05:32.025   964 23382 E ActivityManager: Error reading /data/anr/traces.txt
05-20 10:05:32.025   964 23382 E ActivityManager: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/anr/traces.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
05-20 10:05:32.025   964 23382 E ActivityManager:   at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:458)
05-20 10:05:32.025   964 23382 E ActivityManager:   at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:78)
05-20 10:05:32.025   964 23382 E ActivityManager:   at android.os.FileUtils.readTextFile(FileUtils.java:229)
05-20 10:05:32.025   964 23382 E ActivityManager:   at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService$18.run(ActivityManagerService.java:10322)
05-20 10:05:32.025   964 23382 E ActivityManager: Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
05-20 10:05:32.025   964 23382 E ActivityManager:   at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
05-20 10:05:32.025   964 23382 E ActivityManager:   at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
05-20 10:05:32.025   964 23382 E ActivityManager:   at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:442)
05-20 10:05:32.025   964 23382 E ActivityManager:   ... 3 more